# Java ClassLoader will not load classes generated on-the-fly

Tags: java, dynamic, classloader

The application(standard) classloader will not load classes on if they dont exist on the classpath at program start time.

My program is contained in an executable jar. It compiles Java classes on-the-fly and outputs the resultant class files to a directory on the classpath. The classpath is set explicitly at startup time via the -classpath flag.

Compilation works fine - .class files are generated in the correct place.

However subsequent attempts to load the compiled classes only work if the classes are present at program startup time.

If the .class files are present on disk at program start time the standard application class loader will load them OK. However, if they are not present until after the program has started the ClassLoader throws a ClassNotFound exception. Its almost as if the ClassLoader is caching the disk contents...

My understanding is that one of the thing the ClassLoader does is to search on disk across the classpath for named classes. Is that correct? If so, my approach should work?

I can work-around the problem by using a separate URLClassLoader to load the dynamically compiled classes. However I would like to understand why the standard application ClassLoader fails.

I have done a fair bit of research on this, but still don't understand why it doesn't work. Perhaps I am being a bit thick....

An explanation will be much appreciated :-)

Comment: `It compiles Java classes on-the-fly` What Jar file is this?

Comment: Maybe the ClassLoader indezes the Classpath at start and saves where every class is - If you add another file to it, the ClassLoader won't know.

Comment: Note: This is what I think, I am not sure about that.

Comment: @markspace - The Jar file is mine, containing application code.
The  code compiles plug-ins on the fly.

Comment: (Create &) use a `RamClassLoader`.